# Make Exchange resource decline booking if other resources unavailable

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365

We're setting up a bunch of new meeting rooms as a result of an office move and I'm unsure of how, or if, I can configure something the way it needs to be. One of the meeting rooms is split into three different rooms which can be expanded as needed. We need to be able to book each of the three rooms individually, but also need to be able to book either the left and centre, right and centre, or all three.

Setting up the six different rooms in Exchange is no problem, (1,2,3,1+2,2+3,1+2+3), but is there a way for me to prevent people from booking room 1+2+3 when room 2 is already booked? Or do I just need to tell users that they need to book each room?

We are running a hybrid Exchange Online solution, with an on-prem Exchange 2013 server running the latest CU package. All rooms are setup to automatically accept, and there are no delegates for any of the room scheduling.

Comment: Interesting idea but I've always had people just book each resource separately.

Comment: @TimBrigham Either that, or use booking delegates to manage the room(s).  I recently was asked to nuke multiple calendar instances in this same scenario.  Users can now request just the "whole" room.  This wasn't a particularly large meeting space like a gym or anything, just a large-ish room with dividers.  If OP is referencing a conference center or something similarly large, I think booking sections separately makes sense.

Comment: It's a small room, but it's right  outside the executive block of offices and offers the best views of outside, which means that I have to treat it specially. Basically I need to make sure that if a pleb reserves one small section the execs aren't forced to use one of the alternate rooms, which are actually not as nice. 

It sounds like the only way to do this is by setting up the largest combination as a room which will require a delegate to handle booking.